# why I have a warning in eclipse and how to remove it at last import : The import java.sql.SQLException is never used

Tags: java, jdbc, compiler-errors, tomcat8

I have a warning in eclipse and how to remove it at last import : import java.sql.SQLException; // The import java.sql.SQLException is never used why 
[site of this JDBC example](http://fm4dd.com/database/howto-install-PostgreSQL-jdbc.htm)

```
   //JdbcTestpostgreSQL.java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class JdbcTestPostgreSQL {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println (e);
         System.exit (-1);
      }
      try {
         // open connection to database
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
         //"jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:port/dbname", "user", "dbpass");
         "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.40:5432/postgres", "postgres", "postgres");

         // build query, here we get info about all databases"
         String query = "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false";

         // execute query
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement ();
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery (query);

         // return query result
         while ( rs.next () )
            // display table name
            System.out.println ("PostgreSQL Query result: " + rs.getString ("datname"));
         connection.close ();
      }
      catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
         System.err.println (e);
         System.exit (-1);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have `catch(java.sql.SQLException e)` in your catch clause. Since you are using the fully qualified name, the import is not needed.
If you change that to `catch(SQLException e)`, the warning will disappear.